# z-index не помогает

Tags: html, css

на верху с positio: fixed прикреплена мею, а внизу слайдер с div ом у которых внутри background image который прикрывает этот меню ... как исправить? пробовал все, z-index ставил 9999999999999999999999, у слайдкра ноль даже минус, даже 1, не помог, каждому элементу отделно меню дал z-index не помог, что делать??

```
 введите сюда код
```

Comment: Прикрепите код, воспроизводящий проблему. При редактировании вопроса нажмите `Ctrl`+`M`.

Comment: я попробовал, но там все запутанно, короче не получилос

Comment: а кто обещал, что будет легко?

Comment: у меня целый проект... между слайдом и меню, который прикреплем с верху, есть еще один блок с background-image и у него все порядке, он не пререкрывает ... мне нужно будет целый кускок ставить, чтобы все ясно было, а то и ясно не будет, потому что там еще картинки много есть а без них не понятно

Comment: Зачем целый проект? когда целый проект - это одна большая проблема, надо отказываться от проекта. А вас просят дать минимальный код, воспроизводящий проблему.